# Where can i get a feed for country specific economic announcements?

Tags: fx, calender, economic-calender

I am looking for a feed for country wide economic announcements.  For example CPI announcements etc. I currently use http://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar/ but I have to manually go there and "Export as CSV" then add to my application every week. Is there an API I can use instead? I don't mind paying.

Answer (score 1):

Check:

www.tradingeconomics.com,
www.knoema.com,
www.quandl.com,

I think some of them have API you are looking for ...